# TypeScript Ambient Modules, can't resolve typescript module in another file

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I created module called "mod" with exported function "modNormalize",
I need use its function in my "app.ts" file. I imported module, and add "reference path", but when I run webpack get this error

"ERROR in ./src/app/app.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mod' in '/var/www/type/src/app'
 @ ./src/app/app.ts 4:12-26
 @ multi ./src/app/app.ts
"

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: this is node.d.ts file,
`declare module "url1" {
    export function parse(urlStr: string, parseQueryString?, slashesDenoteHost?): string;
}`

and app.ts

`/// <reference path="node.d.ts"/>
import { parse } from "url1";
parse("a");`

Comment: It works fine with the name "url", but when I change name of module in node.d.ts to "url1" and import it in app.ts as "url1" I get an error